# Links when opened in a new tab or window opened a blank page

Tags: c#

Links in my web application that i made when clicked redirects the page to the supposed page it should redirect to, however, when i right-clicked on the link and opened it on a new tab or window, it will open a new tab or window but the page it opened is blank. How can I fix this? I am using C#, Web Forms.

Comment: STOP YELLING US! WE ARE NOT DEAF!

Comment: @Soner Well not yet, anyway! ;)

Comment: What does the link look like, when you hover over it? Is it a URI or javascript code?

Comment: something like this? javascript:_doPostBack(IDOfTheLink, "")

Answer (score 0):

if you add link as LiteralControl - is HTML Tag

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">fly to google</a>
```

if you add link as asp control

```
HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
        link.NavigateUrl = "http://google.com";
        link.Text = "fly to google";
        link.Attributes.Add("target", "_blank");

        this.Controls.Add(link);
```